# Query multiple tables using one join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query multiple tables that contain the column name 'idClient' for a specific condition.

So far I acquire the tables that I need to query using the following query:

```
SELECT c.name  AS 'ColumnName',
       t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c (nolock)
JOIN        sys.tables  t   (nolock) ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%idClient%'
ORDER BY    TableName,
            ColumnName;
```

This gives me the following result (in reality there are roughly 100 tables returned):

```
+------------+-----------------+
| ColumnName |    TableName    |
+------------+-----------------+
| idClient   | tbClient        |
| idClient   | tbClientContact |
| idClient   | tbInvoice       |
+------------+-----------------+
```

In order for me to find all client records in each of the tables I am currently running 3 separate queries for each table name. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbClientContact (nolock)
    JOIN tbClient (nolock)
        ON tbClientContact.idClient = tbClient.idClient
WHERE tbClient.vcSurname = 'Smith'
```

Instead of running the above query 3 times for each table, is there an easier way to run the same query on all results that are returned as TableName?

GOAL: I have been tasked with - in the example above - removing any client records from a database where the client surname is 'Smith'. I am running the above SELECT query to find whether the idClient of all clients with the surname of 'Smith' will leave orphan records in tables where there is a link of 'idClient'. I am joining tbClient as the column vcSurname does not exist in any other table than tbClient.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think this question would be more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you running the same query 3 times?   I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The short answer is `no`. Can there be more than one row matching your client in each table? I assume Yes. If so, can you describe the kind of structure you want to return from those three tables combined? A single SQL query can only return one dataset, so you'd need a single structure that can hold all the data you want. If there are 3 contacts and 4 invoices, how do you want to fit all of that in?  Or is there some relationship between the tables that you haven't told us?  If so, is that relationship described by foreign key constraints?  There are ways, but they're not going to be "simple".

Comment: @MatBailie thank you for your reply. What if I only want to return 'idClient' from my SELECT query?

Comment: Do you mean something like `SELECT idClient FROM xxx   UNION   SELECT idClient FROM yyy   UNION   SELECT idClient FROM zzz`?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what output you actually want? It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. I can't see why listing all the IDs from each table would be useful? Maybe I missed the point. Or are you really trying to do something practical like link the invoices back to the clients' details, for instance? Are these tables linked by foreign keys? If so you can get one resultset by using INNER JOINs. Please can you make clear what you actual goal is?

Comment: @MatBailie that will deduplicate the resultset. May or may not be intended behaviour.

Comment: @SQL_M true, and using `UNION ALL` would of course remove that problem

Comment: @SQL_M `UNION` removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` keeps them.

Comment: @MatBailie I know, that's exactly what I said... de-duplicate

Comment: Why are you using the nolock hint on system tables? And really the best approach would be to fix the data model. If you have properly defined foreign keys and such this should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
SELECT idClient FROM tbClient WHERE vcSurname = 'Smith'
UNION ALL
SELECT idClient FROM tbClientContact WHERE vcSurname = 'Smith'
UNION ALL
SELECT idClient FROM tbInvoice  WHERE vcSurname = 'Smith'
```

If you need more columns output, all three queries must have the same number of ouput columns and all of the same type

**Edit**
As others have suggested, it would be helpful to know what you are doing as the method you are attempting is never the best way of doing something. However, the cursor solution below should build a dynamic query to do what you want

```
DECLARE @table AS NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR
    -- hey all the tables with the columns LIKE '%idClient%'
    SELECT t.name AS 'TableName'
    FROM        sys.columns c (nolock)
    JOIN        sys.tables  t   (nolock) ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE       c.name LIKE '%idClient%'
    ORDER BY    TableName


-- loop through the results of the query line by line
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- build the query dynamically
    SET @sql =CONCAT(@sql,'SELECT idClient FROM ' + @table +  ' WHERE vcSurname = ''Smith'' UNION ALL ')
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @table
END

-- remove last "UNION ALL" text
SET @sql = STUFF(@sql,LEN(@sql)-9,11,'')
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

**EDIT EDIT**
Just seen your edit. Does your table have foreign / primary key pairs, do the foreign keys have `ON DELETE CASCADE`? If so, it should just be a case of

```
DELETE from tbClient WHERE vcSurname = 'Smith'
```

Comment: This would work, thank you. However, is there a way of automating the construction of this query, considering the results that are returned from the first SELECT query which returns a list of tables as 'TableName'?

Comment: @idektom how would this work? Why would you want a query like that? Don't those tables `tbClientContact` and `tbInvoice` have FK referencing `tbClient`? Do all those tables have `vcSurname` column meaning client's surname? If you were satisfied with `INNER JOIN`ing secondary tables to `tbClient`, which means that you could not get any other records than existing in `tbClient`, what is the point of `UNION`? It won't give you any additional records. What are you trying to do, again?

Comment: Solution edited but as Ivan says, there is something not right here. You shouldn't need to construct queries in this way

Answer (score 2):

For automated query:

After question Edit:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '+c.name+' FROM '+t.name+' T WITH(nolock)
    JOIN tbClient (NOLOCK)
        ON T.idClient = tbClient.idClient
WHERE vcSurname = ''Smith''
        UNION ALL
        '
FROM        sys.columns c (nolock)
JOIN        sys.tables  t   (nolock) ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%idClient%'
```

PRINT the result in text format (ctrl+T).
Copy the complete result and then remove last `UNION ALL`

Comment: what about my post..?

Answer (score 1):

1 Determine involved tables by querying systables (`sysforeignkeys` or `syscolumns` if you don't have FKs).

2 Manually write a comprehensive stored proc that is meant to do everything right

```
create proc dbo.Client_Del
  @client_id int
as
begin try
  if not exists(select 1 from dbo.Client c where c.id = @client_id)
    raiserror("Client %d not found", 16, 1, @client_id)

  begin tran

  delete ct
  from dbo.ClientContacts ct
  where ct.client_id = @client_id

  delete idt
  from dbo.InvoiceDetail idt
  inner join dbo.Invoice i
     on i.invoice_id = idt.invoice_id
  where i.client_id = @client_id

  delete i
  from dbo.Invoice i
  where i.client_id = @client_id

  delete c
  from dbo.Client c
  where c.client_id = @client_id

  commit tran
end try
begin catch
  if @@trancount > 0
     rollback tran
  throw
end catch
GO
```

3 Invoke your stored proc with an argument

```
declare @id int

set @id = (select c.client_id from dbo.Client c where c.LastName = 'Smith')

exec dbo.Client_Del
  @client_id = @id
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure on what is your need. And this post is enhanced code of `@Luv`. Use of this, you just run it.

```
declare @select nvarchar(max) = N''
set @select = 
N'
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N''''
SELECT @sql += '' UNION ALL SELECT ''+c.name+'' FROM ''+t.name+'' T WITH(nolock)
    JOIN tbClient (NOLOCK)
        ON T.idClient = tbClient.idClient
WHERE vcSurname = ''''Smith''''''
FROM        sys.columns c (nolock)
JOIN        sys.tables  t   (nolock) ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE ''%yourColumnName%'' 
set @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '''')
print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
'
exec sp_executesql @select
```